# Code signing certificate on Gitlab CI for electron

Tags: electron, gitlab-ci, code-signing-certificate

I am planning to buy an EV code signing certificate to auto sign a Windows electron build generated by Gitlab CI.

What would be the steps to add it to a Gitlab CI runner and add the rule. I heard EV certs use an USB key, how could I do to bypass this requirement on a virtual Gitlab runner?
How could I test with a self signed certificate on Windows? Unsure on how to generate one.

Answer (score 0):

This is painful.. I'm using SafeNet usb token, and everytime it needs to sign, a dialog that asks for the certificate password will spawn.
But that is not the issue.. gitlab-runner as a windows service cannot find the certificate at all.

Gitlab runner, runs as a windows service, but windows services cannot interact with desktop. So I got it working by stopping and disabled the gitlab-service automatic start (on Services management, set Manual option), and copied the Path to executable value and pasted on a admin cmd window.

[gitlab-runner service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkW2b.png)

This way is not treated as a service and certificate can be found, still spawns for password input, but you can set an option to single-sign-on on advanced options of safenet client app, and only asks once until you restart the pc.